# Resultado inesperado

Tags: c, tipagem, float, divisão

Eu desejo realizar a divisão de dois números inteiros e ter como resultado um valor ponto flutuante.

O seguinte código funciona normalmente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float divInts(int x, int y)
{
    return((float)x/y);
}

void main()
{
    printf("%f",divInts(50,3));
}
```

Porém o código abaixo, que creio ser equivalente ao de cima, não funciona como o esperado, retornando o valor 1.031615 ao se dividir 50/3, ao invés de 16.666667:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void divInts()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    float resultado;

    printf ("Entre o numerador 'x' :\n");
    scanf ("%f", &x);

    printf ("Entre o denominador 'y' :\n");
    scanf ("%f", &y);

    resultado = (float)x / y;

    printf("O resultado da divisao entre x e y, em formato ponto flutuante e : %f\n\n", resultado);
}

void main()
{
    divInts();
}
```

Por qual razão isso acontece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade em compiladores modernos e bem configurados nem compila. O código declara duas variáveis como `int` e depois manda ler como se fossem `float`. Aí o resultado sai errado mesmo. Mas só dá o erro porque o compilador deixou passar algo que não deveria funcionar. Sugiro mudar de compilador ou configurá-lo para não deixar passar este tipo de erro. E mude no código o formatador do `scanf()` para `%d`. Assim é o correto.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;
    int y;
    printf ("Entre o numerador 'x' :\n");
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    printf ("Entre o denominador 'y' :\n");
    scanf ("%d", &y);
    printf("O resultado da divisao entre x e y, em formato ponto flutuante e : %f\n\n", (float)x / y);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/aCc8am). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/amgmyvfh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/ScanfFormat.c).

Outra possibilidade é declarar as variáveis como `float` e aí pega o valor já no tipo completo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float x;
    float y;
    printf ("Entre o numerador 'x' :\n");
    scanf ("%f", &x);
    printf ("Entre o denominador 'y' :\n");
    scanf ("%f", &y);
    printf("O resultado da divisao entre x e y, em formato ponto flutuante e : %f\n\n", x / y);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/lWPJSC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xpizxtsf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/ScanfFormat2.c).

[Documentação do `scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Answer (score 1):

O `x` e o `y` foi declarado no início como `int` e depois você fez a leitura com `scanf ("%f", &y)`, utilizando o `%f`, que é para float. Ou você altera para float o `x` e `y`, ou troca o `%f` para `%f`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void divInts()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    float resultado;
    printf ("Entre o numerador 'x' :\n");
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    printf ("Entre o denominador 'y' :\n");
    scanf ("%d", &y);
    resultado = (float) x / y;
    printf("O resultado da divisao entre x e y, em formato ponto flutuante e : %f\n\n", resultado);
}
main()
{
    divInts();
}
```